# limit WebRTC bandwidth from the client side (browser)

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I know it's possible to limit the upload (sent) bandwidth using "setParameter" on the peer-connection.
I'm looking for a way to limit the download (received) and couldn't find one.
(I don't have control

Am I missing the concept? or there's a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To "limit bandwidth" of realtime data means sending less of it.

There's no `setParameters` on an RTCRtpReceiver and no builtin back channel for this. But you can trivially make your own using e.g. `createDataChannel("myBackchannel")`, provided you have control of both sides. Then have the receiver send parameters back to the sender over it, which then sets them with `setParameters`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be controlled by inserting a `b=` line into the SDP. Support for this varies, until recently Chrome only supported `b=AS` which specified the bandwidth in kilobits per second while Firefox only supported `b=TIAS` which specifies the bandwidth in bits per second.
Both variants ask a remote peer not to send more than this bandwidth.

One of the webrtc samples still [shows the usage](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/) but you will need to deactivate the newer usage of `setParameters`.